Error when trying to install Apache Airflow inside a python virtual environment
I activated a venv and have a terminal (cmd) open in vscode. When I paste the following command
pip install 'apache-airflow==2.10.2' \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.10.2/constraints-3.8.txt"

and run it I get

ERROR: Invalid requirement: "'apache-airflow==2.10.2'": Expected package name at the start of dependency specifier
'apache-airflow==2.10.2'

What could be the problem?

The pip command expects the name, or name==version, of a known package. You used single quotes to type 'package_name==version', try without quotes.
